# Correct methodology for solving this trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

I want the correct method for solving this trigonometric equation

$$\sqrt{\cos(x)\sqrt{\cos(x)\sqrt{\cos(x)\dots}}} =1.$$

I have used my own technique:

\begin{align*}           
\sqrt{\cos(x)\sqrt{\cos(x)\sqrt{\cos(x)\dots}}} &= 1 \\
\cos^\frac{1}{2}(x)\cos^\frac{1}{4}(x)\cos^\frac{1}{8}(x)\dots  &= 1 \\
\log\bigl(\cos^\frac{1}{2}(x)\cos^\frac{1}{4}(x)\cos^\frac{1}{8}(x)\dots\bigr) &= \log{1} \\
\log \bigl(\cos^\frac{1}{2}(x)\bigr) + \log\bigl(\cos^\frac{1}{4}(x)\bigr) + \log\bigl(\cos^\frac{1}{8}(x)\bigr) + \dots &= \log{1} \\
\frac{1}{2}\log\bigl(\cos(x)\bigr) + \frac{1}{4}\log\bigl(\cos(x)\bigr) + \frac{1}{8}\log\bigl(\cos(x)\bigr) + \dots &= \log{1} \\
\log\bigl(\cos(x)\bigr)\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\dots\right) &= \log{1}
\end{align*}
The series in the brackets is an infinite geometric series by summing it I get
\begin{align*}
         \cos(x)\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}} &= 1 \\
         \cos(x)\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}} &= 1 \\
         \cos(x) &= 1 \\
         x &= \arccos(1) \\
         x &= 0
\end{align*}
So the solution set is $\{2n\pi\}$.

This is how I have solved the given problem but I want is there any other method for solving this equation.

Comment: Nice idea, but you could have seen it a little earlier: If $\cos(x)=1$, then you only multiply and take the root of ones. The solution $x=2\pi n$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ can be easily seen.

Comment: Also, you made a mistake, when removing the $\log$ on both sides, the value of the infinite series will appear as an exponent of $\cos(x)$. But since the value is $1$, it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I want the your method to understand it in-depth.

Answer (score 3):

For any $A>0$,
$$
A=\sqrt{\cos x \sqrt{\cos x \sqrt{\cos x \ldots}}}=\sqrt{A \cos x} \implies \cos x = A.
$$
In your case, $A=1$, so $\cos x = 1$, so $x \in \{0, \pm 2\pi, \pm 4\pi,\ldots\}$.

Comment: Not for any $A>0$. It has to be $0\le A\le1$ Other wise $\cos x = A$ has no solution.